# how to a specific delete line in textbox

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, string, linq

Suppose that a paragraph in a multiline textbox contained:

```
stringrandom@good
stringra12312@good
stringr2a123@bad
strsingra12312@good
strinsgr2a123@bad
```

I want to produce output like this:

```
stringrandom@good
stringra12312@good
strsingra12312@good
```

I have tried using

```
  If TextBox1.Lines.Count > 2 Then
      Dim newList As List(Of String) = TextBox1.Lines.ToList
      If newList.Contains("@bad") Then
          newList.RemoveAt(newList.Item(newList.Contains("@bad")))
      End If

      TextBox1.Lines = newList.ToArray
  End If
```

It does not work, does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: For future questions please always define 'does not work'. This key phrase is very common, and is not self-explanatory.

Answer (score 4):

You may use LINQ to query the list.

```
If TextBox1.Lines.Count > 2 Then
    Dim newList As List(Of String) = TextBox1.Lines.ToList
    newList = newList.Where(Function(x) Not x.Contains("bad")).ToList
End If
```

In fact you don't really need the If statement:

```
Dim newList As List(Of String) = TextBox1.Lines.ToList
newList = newList.Where(Function(x) Not x.Contains("bad")).ToList
```

And You can even do it simpler by applying the LINQ directly to the TextBox:

```
Dim newList As List(Of String) = TextBox1.Lines _
                                 .ToList _
                                 .Where(Function(x) Not x.Contains("bad")) _
                                 .ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the regular expressions (`System.Text.RegularExpressions`). Try this:

```
Dim lines = textBox1.Lines _
    .Where(Function(l) Not Regex.Match(l, "\w*@bad").Success) _
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be (C#);

```
const string mail = "stringrandom@good";
const string mail1 = "stringra12312@good";
const string mail2 = "stringr2a123@bad";
const string mail3 = "strsingra12312@good";
const string mail4 = "strinsgr2a123@bad";

var mails = new string[] { mail, mail1, mail2, mail3, mail4 }; //List of addresses

var x = mails.Where(e => e.Contains("good")).ToList(); //Fetch where the list contains good
```

Or in VB

```
Dim x = mails.Where(Function(e) e.Contains("good")).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your were close to begin with.  Use FindIndex instead.

```
  If TextBox1.Lines.Count > 2 Then
      Dim newList As List(Of String) = TextBox1.Lines.ToList
      If newList.Contains("@bad") Then
          newList.RemoveAt(newList.FindIndex(Function(x) x.Contains("@bad")))
      End If

      TextBox1.Lines = newList.ToArray
  End If
```